# Proof $(-a)+(-b)=-(a+b)$ directly from the axioms of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove it. I did this, I want to know if it is correct:

$a+(-a)= 0$   (Existence of an additive inverse)

$a+(-a) +(-1)(a)=(-1)(a)$

$(a-a)+(-a) =(-1)(a)$   (distributive property of sum)

$-a=(-1)(a)\quad\forall a \in\mathbb{R}$

$(-a)+(-b)=(-1)(a)+(-1)(b)=(-1)(a+b) = -(a+b)$

The last step associativity property of sum.

Thank you so much

Comment: When you say "distributive property of sum," I'm not sure what you mean. Looks like you mean associative property. You also simply replace (-1)a with $-a$ to prove that $(-1)a=-a$, which is perhaps a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is okay, except it uses $-a = (-1)\cdot a$, and what you are trying to prove  is true just using rules of addition. (Your proof that $(-1)a=-a$ is a bit confusing - what is the "distributive law of sum?" Where did the $-1$ go on the left side? Also, you use the minus symbol in "a-a," which is not one of the fundamental operations in most axioms.)

There is a more direct proof that doesn't use $-1$ or multiplcation.

Hint: Compute the following sum in two different ways:

$$(-a) + (-b) + a + b + (-(a+b))$$

You'll need the associative and commutative laws of addition, and that $x+(-x)=0$ and that $y+0=y$.

Answer (score 2):

First we prove that $0.a=0$. Indeed by distributive axiom we have
$$0.a=(0+0).a=0.a+0.a,$$
then by  adding the additive inverse of $0.a$ to both sides we find $0.a=0$. Now we have $(-1).a=-a$, in fact:
$$0=(1+(-1)).a=a+(-1).a,$$
so $$(-1).a=-a.$$
Finally we prove your equality:
$$(-a)+(-b)=(-1).a+(-1).b=(-1).(a+b)=-(a+b).$$
That's all.

Comment: Perhaps you should remark that the first identity is obtained adding the additive inverse to both sides, and the second one is obtained by *uniqueness* of the additive inverse.

Comment: That's correct. it seems clear.

Comment: Yes, but what the OP asks is also "clear", so when one wants a proof relying on the very axioms it seems to be a good idea to quote them at every little step we make to justify stuff.

Comment: In his question, th OP  assumed the existence of the additive inverse (fourth axiom of group) so I need not to prove this fact.

Comment: Neither said I that you should, @sbr: I talked about the **uniqueness** of the inverse, which is what gives the final touch.

Comment: @DonAntonio Cordially. Thanks for comments.

Comment: Any time, @sbr. +1